# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType' in Python

Tags: python

I'm getting this error in my code:

> File "C:\Users\angelica\Documents\ING. DE SISTEMAS\Semestre
> VI\ADA\popes.py", line 35, in solve  upper_bound =
> upper_bound_search(popes, 0, len_popes-1 , n)
>
> File "C:\Users\angelica\Documents\ING. DE SISTEMAS\Semestre
> VI\ADA\popes.py", line 9, in upper_bound_search
> if x > arr[hi]:
>
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and
> 'NoneType'.

I know it must be an error of logic, but I don´t seem to see where's the problem. If anyone could help me I would appreciated.

```
from sys import stdin

MAX = 5005
Y,P,pope = None,None,[ None for _ in range(MAX) ]

def upper_bound_search(arr, lo, hi, x):
  if x <= arr[lo]:
    return lo
  if x > arr[hi]:
    return -1

  mid = ((lo+hi))//2
  if x == arr[mid]:
    return mid

  elif x > arr[mid]:
    if mid+1 <= hi and x <= arr[mid+1]:
      return mid+1
    else:
      return upper_bound_search(arr, mid+1, hi, x)
  else:
    if mid-1 >= lo  and x > arr[mid-1]:
      return mid
    else:
      return upper_bound_search(arr,lo, mid-1, x)



def solve(year, popes):
  a,b,c = -1, -1, -1
  len_popes = len(popes)
  for i in range(len_popes):
    y = popes[i] 
    n = y + year -1
    upper_bound = upper_bound_search(popes, 0, len_popes-1 , n)
    temp = (upper_bound - i)
    if a < temp :
      a = temp
      b = y
      c = popes[upper_bound]
  return a,b,c
def main():
  global Y,P,pope
  line = stdin.readline()
  while len(line)!=0:
    Y,P = int(line),int(stdin.readline())
    for p in range(P): pope[p] = int(stdin.readline())
    ans = solve(Y, pope)
    print('{0} {1} {2}'.format(ans[0], ans[1], ans[2]))
    line = stdin.readline()
    if len(line)!=0: line = stdin.readline()

main()
```

Also, I'm adding the entry i'm using as test.

```
11
20
1
2
3
6
8
12
13
13
15
16
17
18
19
20
20
21
25
26
30
31
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: I just edited and added the error message, thanks for your annotation!

Comment: Obviously, `arr[hi]` is a `None`. In fact, the whole list is `None`s. What do you expect to find in it?

Comment: It would seem to suggest that `arr` has no value with an index of `hi` in that recursion

Comment: @DYZ if the whole list was `None` then the `x <= arr[lo]` would have raised an error too

Comment: "I know it must be an error of logic, but I don´t seem to see where's the problem." - Well, do you at least *understand* the problem? Do you know what `NoneType` means, or what `None` is? Do you think it *should* be possible to do this comparison? (If so, how should it work?) If not, then what is the actual point of confusion? For example, were you surprised that one of the values is `None`? Were you able to figure out which one it was? etc. etc. It is not possible to help you understand something unless we first know *why you don't understand it already*.

Comment: I must apologise, i didn't add the "main" function since I thought it wasn't neccesary to help solve the error. Again, I apologise and now added the "main" function.

Comment: I recommend adding "sanity check" print statements throughout your code to inspect variable between each statement.  (It would be better to single step debug the code, if you are using an IDE like WingIDE or WingPRO).  You may not be getting the values you expect every step of the way.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your global `pope` list to a list of 5005 `None`s. This means `len(pope)` will evaluate to 5005. The data you are using to test with has much less than 5005 values.

When you call `upper_bound_search()`, you call it like this:

```py
upper_bound = upper_bound_search(popes, 0, len_popes-1 , n)
```

This means `hi` will have a value of 5004 (5005 - 1 = 5004).

In your `main()` function, you only populate the first `P` indices of the `pope` global list:

```py
for p in range(P): pope[p] = int(stdin.readline())
```

So only the first `P` items in the list will have integer values, and all other items in the list will have the value `None`. With the test data you provided, `P` is much smaller than 5005.

Then, when the line

```py
if x > arr[hi]:
```

is reached in `upper_bound_search()`, `hi` has the value 5004. `arr[hi]` evaluates to `None`, and `x` is an integer. The `>` operator is not defined for `None`, since it doesn't make any sense to say `None` is less than or greater than some numeric value.

What you could try instead is passing `P-1` as the value for `hi`. Or you could also try letting your `pope` list grow dynamically by appending data instead of wasting memory with a really large list.

Answer (score -1):

In your global declaration

```
MAX = 5005
```

`Y,P,pope = None,None,[None] * MAX`

You are comparing int and none for variable pope in your upperbound search. None is a non-value in python equivalent to null in some other programming languages. Consider using 0 in the array, that way you can perform integer comparison.

Comment: Would using zeroes for "null values" break the OP's algorithm though? What if zeroes were possible real data values? I think the OP really needs to properly track how many items in their list contain real data.